# JFrog CLI returns "The handle is invalid" when adding git info to build

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I noticed that in my Jenkins builds, JFrog CLI tends to fail when adding git build info:

```
jfrog rt build-add-git jfrog_cli_test 42
[Error] read D:\workspace\jfrog_cli_test\.git: The handle is invalid.
```

There does not seem to be a particular reason, as this will still happen with clean builds. Of noteworthy importance though is the size of the git repository (~2GB).

I am running JFrog CLI 1.14.0 in verbose mode (env variable `JFROG_CLI_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG`) but this does not give more details about the issue.

Any idea what is happening here? I will have a go with the Jenkins plugin meanwhile.

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue with the latest version (1.23.0)? We have made quite a few updates to the code since the 1.14 release so any details are appreciated.

Comment: updating fixed the problem.